# If a database is in memory does it still need indexing?

Tags: optimization

**INFO** I'm following lessons on databases. We're learning about indices now.

**Question**

If big parts of a table are in the memory, would using a index still have benefits?

**My side**

I would assume indexing makes a search always faster, so yes it would have benefits. I hope this is not to much opinion based and maybe someone have a good explained reason why or why not it has benefits.

Comment: **OF COURSE!** even if it's in memory, if you have to scan tens of thousands of pages for a full table scan, that's vastly less efficient than being able to walk through an index tree on a handful of pages..... also: it's much more likely that the tens of index pages are kept in memory, rather than **ALL** of thousands or tens of thousands of actual data pages

Comment: thank you @marc_s Didn't thought of such big data tables.

Comment: Regarding the SQL Server In-memory OLTP feature, the tables *must* have at least one index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an index will help.  Without an index all the RDBMS can do is start at the beginning of the data and work its way toward the end, stopping when it finds what it's looking for.  This is a [O(N)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) operation.  With a B-Tree index in place it reduces to O(log(N)).  This is true whether the data is held on disk or in memory.

Comment: You wrote `stopping when it finds what it's looking for` but I guess it would traverse whole table even if it finds the required row this is how scan works

Comment: If the query has an explicit or implicit limit, it may not need to scan the whole table.  If a cursor is being used, it will stop scanning when it matches a row and resume scanning when the next row is requested.

Comment: But what if it is not a cursor. statement was made as general statement which is wrong